# Pytorch transfer learning predictions

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I have been following the pytorch transfer learning tutorial,and following the tutorial to my own dataset i have arrived at this

```
model_conv = train_model(model_conv, criterion, optimizer_conv,
                     exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=25)

Epoch 1/1
......
......
......
Epoch 24/24
train Loss: 0.8674 Acc: 0.5784
val Loss: 1.2930 Acc: 0.4583
Training complete in 43m 24s
Best val Acc: 0.486111
```

The tutorial ends here,but im not exaclty sure how do i get predictions for my new images?

Any suggestions would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by `predictions`? Which class does your image belong to?

Comment: @jdhao By predictions i mean,how do i feed it new images so that it outputs discreet labels .

Comment: Pass in inputs to your model_conv like so: model_conv(imgs). 'imgs' should be the same dimensions as the data you used to train it with. That should return the probabilities or whatever the model returns at the end as defined when you wrote forward()

Comment: Alright !@Littleone thanks for your time,let me check thisout

Comment: I had to shutdown the jupyter notebook earlier so let me retrain this and ill reply you

Comment: @Littleone It works really well,Since i have 3 classes my predictions come out as `Variable containing:
 2.4276  4.9323 -7.6616` ,Is there any way i could only get it to output the max class name instead of three scores?

Comment: [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)

Comment: @Littleone Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply feed the new image (in the same format as the images in your training dataset were) to the model:

```
labels = model_conv(new_images)
```